# Reflection and enlargement of a complex number z.

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I came across this question in a year 12 mathematics book, under the complex number section.

*Show that $\frac{1}{z}$ is a reflection and enlargement of z.*

I assume the enlargement means the distance from the origin to the point z.

Could somebody please clarify my attempted solution.

Let $z = x + iy$, then
$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{z} \times \frac{\bar{z}}{\bar{z}}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\bar{z}}{z\bar{z}}
$$

$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}
$$

Since $\bar{z} = x - iy$ and $|z|^2 = x^2 + y^2$

$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2}
$$

or

$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \left( x - iy \right)
$$

The $x - iy$ component represents a reflection in the Real (X) axis, and the $\dfrac{1}{x^2 + y^2}$ factor $\left( \dfrac{1}{|z|^2} \right)$ represents an enlargement provided $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ $\left( |z|^2 < 1 \right)$ .

Is that the correct logic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your algebra looks correct.. Indeed, $|1/z|=1/|z|$, so inversion enlarges points with $|z|<1$ and shrinks points with $|z|>1$.

Comment: My only criticism of your posting is that I feel that you should have **stopped** the algebra, after concluding that $$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}. $$  In some Complex Analysis problems (and I feel that this is one of them), it is better to avoid using the $z = x + iy$ **weapon**.

Comment: Your last equation is slighty off, you want $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ (it is always $\geq 0$). Otherwise your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thanks red_trumpet.  I have changed $x^2 + y^2 < 1$.  It was my mistake originally.

Comment: Thanks  user2661923 I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: I removed the `complex-geometry` tag. As the description of the tag says: *For elementary questions about geometry in the complex plane, use the tags (complex-numbers) and (geometry) instead.*

Comment: Just asking: Was the term really _enlargement_ and not _inversion_ (in the unit circle)?

Comment: Andrew, the question really said $ {enlargement} $.  This is what confused me.